# How much current can a MAX II I/O pin safely sink? 16 or 55mA?

Tags: digital-logic, programmable-logic

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-much-current-can-a-microcontroller-dsp-pin-sink-source).

As far as I understood, an I/O pin configured as LVTTL output can be programmed to source/sink up to 16mA. This is what the [MAX II handbook](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/max2/max2_mii5v1.pdf) says in Table 2.6:

[image: MAX II Programmable Drive Strength]

But the same handbook has this graph about I<sub>OH</sub>, in Figure 5.1, saying that the maximum strength is around 55mA:
[image: MAX II output drive strength]

So which value should I take into account if I want an LVTTL pin sink the current required to drive a LED with forward current of 20mA (given I'll add a current limiting resistor)? Is it safe to operate in these conditions?

Comment: These values seem not to be the specifications for absolute maximum values. Look for abs. max. in the datasheet.

Comment: Abs. max. current per pin is +/- 25mA. And they have a link in the datasheet for a led driving app note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the graph shows maximum total current for all pins.

The datasheet is clear that 25mA is the maximum allowed per pin.

What the 16mA max in the table denotes is the maximum current the output pin can sink and still maintain a valid Vol logic level for 3.3V logic (0.8V).

But for an LED driver you don’t need to maintain a valid logic level.

It just means if you draw 20mA the voltage at the output pin may slightly exceed 0.8V.

Just take that into account in your resistor calculation.

Comment: "0.8V" should read "0.2V" - that's the specification for LVCMOS33 and also what the output achieves according to figure 5.1.

Comment: If specs says 16mA at 0.2V what is Zol?  12.5 ohms even better than 25 Ohms. No brainer

Comment: So is it 0.8 or 0.2V? If I take that into account in resistor calculation, resistor values will be wildly different: with Vcc=3.3V and Vf(led)=2.1V, (3.3-2.1-0.2)/0.02 = 50Ω and (3.3-2.1-0.8)/0.02 = 20Ω.

Comment: I think we were both wrong - appears the proper number for Vol is 0.4V for LVTTL (google 'lvttl voltage levels') and 0.4V or 0.5V for LVCMOS33 depending on site. Whatever - you can see this is exposing a fragile design where LED current is not tightly controlled. You can get tighter control by increasing the drive voltage (do you have 5V around?) or lower the current (do you really need 20mA? - that's awfully bright for a visible LED).

Comment: I actually don't know if I need 20mA. I thought it was simpler to design my circuit for the rated LED current then use PWM to fine-tune the brightness. But I see that with a lower current, the voltage between the CPLD pin and ground will be lower and will impact less on the LED brightness.

Comment: A typical green or red LED only needs about 5mA these days.

Answer (score 0):

The graph shows how much current it will sink if the pin is being driven low as a function of how much voltage is externally applied to the pin. This says nothing about how much current it can *safely* sink, just how much it *will* sink. The table, on the other hand, tells you the amount of current it can safely sink. This lets you determine what your pull-up and pull-down resistors should be, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

How to use logic as a low power driver?

20mA? Yes. very Safe. - ALWAYs. There is confusion to some members on CMOS part numbers This is not TTL., yet TTL works too on low side.-

This Zout is rather constant from linear mode operation.

> So for NON-LOGIC LEVEL operations such as driving LEDs you can and may exceed the Logic level current and use less than the Absolute maximum current, which is temperature limited.
> .
> I gather some folks think 74LVT CMOS is some BJT or TTL technology. But it is just 3.3V logic with TTL input thresholds like 74HCxxx which is <6V logic.
> "TTL threshold" is 1.3 to 1.5V roughly due to 2 diode drops or Vbe drops should NOT be confused with CMOS parts emulating the same threshold rather than Vdd/2.

Most 3.6V logic (e.g. most certain CMOS family 74AVCxx) at 3.3V has a 25 ohm driver +/-50% over temp and batches.

Thus nominal driver dissipation is 20mA x 25R=50mW= low temp rise, 55mA x 25R=138mW which is max temp rise. Or only 50/138 x 100% ratio of max with reasonable margin.

Yet this curve shows 0.5V/30mA = 17 Ohms or 25R-8=-33% thus even 33% lower or better for I^2Ron=Pd proportional to Ron=Vol/Iol but will rise with ambient temp and +ve tolerances.

Bottom line

Driver heat dissipation say for low side which may be better in some "driver" IC's but often symmetrical for generic IC's **MUST be evaluated by Pd=I^2R using R=Rol=Zol=Vol/Iol or sink current at rated Vol max. This voltage will rise linearly with current. The load power is much more the than driver, albeit the load is puny.